# Tag: Synonym TFS with Team Foundation Server

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we make the following tags a synonym: [tfs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tfs) -> [team-foundation-server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server)

Answer (score 4):

[team-foundation-server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server) should be the base tag and [tfs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tfs) should be mapped to it to be in line with other synonyms.